# How to get bivariate normal probability distribution with specified standard deviation and angle in python

Tags: python, numpy, normal-distribution, ellipse, probability-distribution

I want to get a bivariate normal probability distribution(hereafter referred to as BNPD) from ellipse parameters. As shown in the illustraion below, the length of the major axis of the ellipse will be taken as 3 times the standard deviation of BNPD, the same to the minor axis, and the rotation angle of ellipse is taken as the rotation angle of BNPD.

[image]

This is the python test code, not success yet:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

# initialize ellispe parameters
size = 500
ctx = 280
cty = 220
width_radius = 40
height_radius = 120
theta = 45 

# draw a reference line and ellipse
bg = np.ones((size,size, 3))
cv.line(bg,(0,int(size/2)),(size,int(size/2)),(0,0,0),1)
cv.line(bg,(int(size/2),0),(int(size/2),size),(0,0,0),1)
cv.ellipse(bg,(ctx,cty),(width_radius,height_radius),theta,0,360,(0,0,255),2)
cv.imshow("result", bg)
cv.waitKey(0)

# convert ellipse parameters to bivariate normal probability distribution parameters
mean_x = ctx - size//2
mean_y = cty - size//2
sigma_x = width_radius/(3*np.cos(theta)) # I doubt here
sigma_y = height_radius/(3*np.sin(theta))

gaussian_x = lambda x: np.exp(-(x-mean_x)**2/(2*(sigma_x**2)))/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi) * sigma_x)
gaussian_y = lambda y :np.exp(-(y-mean_y)**2/(2*(sigma_y**2)))/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi) * sigma_y)
X = np.linspace(-size/2, size/2, size)
Y = np.linspace(-size/2, size/2, size)

result_x = gaussian_x(X).reshape(-1,1)
result_y = gaussian_y(Y).reshape(1,-1)
result_xy = np.dot(result_x, result_y)

# visualize bivariate normal probability distribution
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.imshow(result_xy)
plt.show()
```

Run above code, it shows:
[image]
[image]
As you can see, the center and angle of ellipse is not correspond to the mean and angle of BNPD.

-------------------------update-----------------------------

As @Matt Pitkin suggest, I try out the `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal` with deduced covariance matrix, but from the plotted graph, it seems the rotation angle is slightly smaller than 45°. The code is:

```py
phi = theta
semiMajorAxis = width_radius
semiMinorAxis = height_radius

varX1 = semiMajorAxis**2 * np.cos(phi)**2 + semiMinorAxis**2 * np.sin(phi)**2
varX2 = semiMajorAxis**2 * np.sin(phi)**2 + semiMinorAxis**2 * np.cos(phi)**2
cov12 = (semiMajorAxis**2 - semiMinorAxis**2) * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(phi) 
mean = [mean_x, mean_y]
covariance = [[varX1, cov12], 
              [cov12,varX2]]
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
xy = np.stack((X, Y), -1)
fxy = multivariate_normal.pdf(xy, mean=mean, cov=covariance)
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.imshow(fxy)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Are you happy to use the [`scipy.stats.multivariate_normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html#scipy.stats.multivariate_normal) function? If so, I'd suggest looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41807958/convert-position-confidence-ellipse-to-covariance-matrix to calculate your covariance matrix and then input that into `multivariate_normal` as in the example shown in the docs.

Comment: @MattPitkin Hi, it is OK to use `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal` function, I updated my question, there is still some problem.

Comment: Make sure `phi` is converted to radians.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks's to @Matt Pitkin's guidance in the comment, the final solution is :

```py
phi =  theta*np.pi/180
semiMajorAxis = width_radius
semiMinorAxis = height_radius

varX1 = semiMajorAxis**2 * np.cos(phi)**2 + semiMinorAxis**2 * np.sin(phi)**2
varX2 = semiMajorAxis**2 * np.sin(phi)**2 + semiMinorAxis**2 * np.cos(phi)**2
cov12 = (semiMajorAxis**2 - semiMinorAxis**2) * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(phi) 
mean = [mean_x, mean_y]
covariance = [[varX1, cov12], 
              [cov12,varX2]]
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
xy = np.stack((X, Y), -1)
fxy = multivariate_normal.pdf(xy, mean=mean, cov=covariance)
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.imshow(fxy)
plt.show()
```

This is the newest plot result:
[image]